# Count Performance optimisation

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008

I got 2 versions of basically the same code. (See below) Version 1 is running at 2 seconds, version 2 is running at .5 - .6 seconds. There are 10 million rows currently from where I am selecting from, but this number goes up pretty fast. I would like to go even lower if possible. The problem is that I use Version 2, and I need to call that 30 times (different statuses, different usernames, etc), the final number is still going to be too big for what I need. Is there a 3rd version I could use instead? Or is there any other way I could make this to be even faster? Or the only thing that I could do is play with indexes.

Basically all these counts would be displayed in the most visited screen in a web application, and 30 * .5 seconds sounds a bit too much when 1000 users are using the system in the same time.

Version 1

```
declare @a1 datetime; set @a1 = GETDATE()

declare @int1 INT,@int2 INT,@int3 INT,@int4 INT,@int5 INT,@int6 INT,@int7 INT,@int8 INT

select @int1 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'a'
select @int2 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'b'
select @int3 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'c'
select @int4 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'd'
select @int5 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'e'
select @int6 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'f'
select @int7 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'g'
select @int8 = COUNT(Id) from ToDos where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId = 'h'

select @int1, @int2, @int3, @int4, @int5, @int6, @int7, @int8

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @a1, GETDATE())
```

Version 2

```
declare @a1 datetime; set @a1 = GETDATE()

select stringUserId, count(stringUserId)
from ToDos
where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId in ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
group by stringUserId
order by COUNT(stringUserId) desc

SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @a1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Why do you need to call the second version 30 times? Afaik you only need one query to select all necessary informations. You just have to remove the `StatusId`-filter. Add it to the `Group By`. Then the result contains all status' counts which seems to be what you need.

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Using [Query analyzer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: it's sql-server not mysql. But you're right anyway

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, I just have that comment on a notepad to easy copy/paste. If you see has both links ;) .... For Ash, the point is we need see the execution plan to see where we can improve the query. Specially what index can help.

Answer (score 1):

Try conditional count.

```
select 
     @int1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'a' THEN 1 END), 
     @int2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'b' THEN 1 END), 
     @int3 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'c' THEN 1 END), 
     @int4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'd' THEN 1 END), 
     @int5 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'e' THEN 1 END), 
     @int6 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'f' THEN 1 END), 
     @int7 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'g' THEN 1 END), 
     @int8 = COUNT(CASE WHEN stringUserId = 'h' THEN 1 END)
from ToDos 
where StatusId = 1
```

FYI: I didnt include the `ELSE` part for `CASE` because for default will return `NULL` and `COUNT` doesnt count nulls

Comment: any update on this question? Were you able to check the query plan?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select a.* from (select stringUserId, count(stringUserId) as IDCount
from ToDos
where StatusId = 1 and stringUserId in ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h')
group by stringUserId) a
order by a.IDCount desc
```

that eliminates the count function from the order by

Comment: Are you sure that make a difference? Because the `order by` is already after the `group by`

Comment: The order by would have to calculate the count as well. So the count is happening twice. I have found this technique made improvements to some things in the past, but not having access to the OP's data I do not know if it will help in this case.  The order things are in the written query bears no relationship to the order the database engine may decide to do things.